# BrowserDomAdapter changes are not reflecting in out side of angular2 context

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to change text value outside of Angular2 context using BrowserDomAdapter it is working fine.

But change value is not reflecting on model/component/directive.
I am actually looking for $apply similar kind of functionality in anuglar2.
I get to know that we can achieve it by using Zone.js
Even it is not working.

following is my code snippet, any help/suggestion is appreciated.

`     //app component
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {DefaultDirective} from './default.directive';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl:"./templates/default.tpl.html",
      directives: [DefaultDirective]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
        color:string = "Red..";
    }

```
// default.tpl.html
<div>
    ===>{{color}}
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="color" [defaultColor]="color"/>
</div>

import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserDomAdapter } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter';
@Directive({
    selector: '[defaultColor]',
})
export class DefaultDirective {
  private el: HTMLElement;
  dom:BrowserDomAdapter;
  constructor(el: ElementRef,public zone:NgZone) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
    this.dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular( ( )=>{
      this.zone.run(()=>{ 
        this.dom.setValue(this.el,"Adding some content fro ngOnInit"); 
         // I am changing value of a text field out side of angular context.
         // Value is updating but model is not reflecting
         //Here i can use @Input/@Output but I would like to change it in out side of angular context.
        });
    });
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't monitors any DOM changes, not inside Angular components nor outside. You might want to emit an event outside Angular and listen to that event inside Angular to update the model in the event handler.

You can listen to global events by prefixing the event name with `window:` or `document:`

```
@HostListener('window:mytextupdate', ['$event']) 
_onTextUpdate(event) {
  this.text = event.detail;
}
```

Comment: What do you need `zone.runOutsideAngular()`for? I can't make much sense of your code example here. What should `this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => { this.zone.run(() => {... }) });` do? Looks like a noop to me.

Comment: my apologies for the confusion, what i am trying to do here is? I would like to use JQuery UI date picker in angular2. Can you suggest me the best way to update a modal of a component/directive

Comment: How is jQuery UI date picker related to "modal of a component/directive"?

Comment: Assume i  have a student component with following fields student name, id, dob, gender,... fields. here for DOB i am using JQuery Ui datepicker. When I select dob date. student.dob has to be updated. This is what my expectation.   In angularJS, I will create a date directive, on selection of a date. I will do $scope.$apply. In angular2 I am looking similar kind of functionality.    Many people saying we can achieve it  by using Zone.js, but it is not helping me here.

Comment: How is that related to "modal of a component/directive"?